# Using MOSFETs to control 3 led modes

Tags: led, mosfet, switches

I have 2 LEDs (3W each) and 3 switches. I want first switch to power LED 1, 2nd switch to power both LEDs, and 3rd switch to power LED 2 (3 modes of lighting: 1st, 2nd or both LEDs on). My power supply is 3.6V Li-ion battery. MOSFETs that I'm using are TSM2302 and my schematic is as follows:

[image: schematics]
my idea here was, that when I press switch 2, it will open the two transistors creating a link between switches 1 and 3 (and lighting both LEDs), but when I press switches 1 or 3, the link is not there and thus only one LED lights.

But what happens is, <s>when I press switch 1 (counting from the top) 1st LED turns on (as expected), when I press switch 3 both LEDs light up (only 2nd should) and when I press switch 2, which should power 2 LEDs, only LED 2 blinks once.</s> both LEDs light up no matter which switch I press.

It is possible my circuit is not soldered well, but it's the first time I'm playing with transistors so I have a strong feeling my schematic might be wrong.

All pull down resistors are 1M and gate resistors 100k.

Comment: ˙ǝɔᴉu s,ʇɐɥ┴ ˙ʎʞs ǝɥʇ oʇ dn ƃuᴉʇuᴉod punoɹפ

Answer (score 0):

There is no voltage to drive the gates of the MOSFETs connected to the LEDs when switch 2 is pressed. You could also have leakage currents due to contamination from soldering. It would only take a few uA of leakage current to turn on a FET with 1M pull down resistor.

Comment: Sorry if it's incorrectly marked in my schematics, drains of both transistors on the left are connected to the switch 2 (and coincidentally that's what I forgot to solder, hence my update in the question)

Comment: In that case current can flow through the body diode of either of the FETs on the left turning on both FETs.

Comment: oh, I haven't thought about that, but it makes perfect sense

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make use of schottky diodes instead of these two additional mosfets to connect the switches to the desired led mosfet gates.
Look for the BAT54 series.